# Accuracy of Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, performance

I am performing Named Entity Recognition using Stanford NER. I have successfully trained and tested my model. Now I want to know:

1) What is the general way of measuring accuracy of NER model ?? For example what techniques or approaches are used ??

2) Is there any built-in method in STANFORD NER for evaluating the accuracy ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition#Formal_evaluation :

> To evaluate the quality of a NER system's output, several measures
>   have been defined. While accuracy on the token level is one
>   possibility, it suffers from two problems: the vast majority of tokens
>   in real-world text are not part of entity names as usually defined, so
>   the baseline accuracy (always predict "not an entity") is
>   extravagantly high, typically >90%; and mispredicting the full span of
>   an entity name is not properly penalized (finding only a person's
>   first name when their last name follows is scored as ½ accuracy).
>
> In academic conferences such as CoNLL, a variant of the F1 score has
>   been defined as follows:
>
> - Precision is the number of predicted entity name spans that line up exactly with spans in the gold standard evaluation data. I.e. when
>     [Person Hans] [Person Blick] is predicted but [Person Hans Blick] was
>     required, precision for the predicted name is zero. Precision is then
>     averaged over all predicted entity names.
> - Recall is similarly the number of names in the gold standard that appear at exactly the same location in the predictions.
> - F1 score is the harmonic mean of these two.
>
> It follows from the above definition that any prediction that misses a
>   single token, includes a spurious token, or has the wrong class,
>   "scores no points", i.e. does not contribute to either precision or
>   recall.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you run a test against labeled data (the `-testFile` option), then Stanford NER will report entity level F1 scores, and a micro-average entity-level F1 at the end of the run.